# Zsh Shell commands

Tags: git, shell, zsh

I want to install `nvm`, but I don't understand what directory I am in.
It seems that I'm stuck in my git (ariadna_natsuki). Thanks for your help!

[image: Ubuntu terminal screenshot]

Comment: The `~` indicates that you  are in your home directory, `/home` implies that you are one level lower, `/` is the absolute root directory.

Comment: Usually, it does not matter what directory you are in, but I suppose it depends on your usage of the word "install".  If you are on ubuntu, you probably just want something like `sudo apt-get install nvm`, and the current working directory is irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry, I was second away answering the question when it was closed.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot is inaccessible. However, You may try the 'pwd' command, to see on which directory you are currently at.

Answer (score 0):

The last line you are in home directory, if your git repo in your Desktop you have to access it by

```
cd ariadna_natsuki/Desktop/name of your repo
```

if you don't know where it is your repo keep displaying content by:

```
ls /home/Desktop
```

or use

```
pwd
```

to see your current directory